# Alpha sort stringgrid

Tags: delphi

How to alpha sort a stringgrid on a form on a given column in Delphi?

Comment: String lists don't have columns. They're just a flat list of strings. Please be more specific about what you want.

Comment: VCL stringlist populated with some data in 2 columns

Comment: you've asked two identical questions. You want to know how to specify a custom sort compare function.

Comment: string lists don't have columns. What do you mean?

Comment: Is this a homework related question, if so add the tag please :)

Comment: @Rawn Please could you do something about the two identical questions. I suggest you delete the other one and ask all your questions in this one.

Comment: Where does the data come from? Have you considered using a virtual control, e.g. virtual list view in details view? This allows you to sort the underlying data and let the presentation reflect it without having to poke data in and out of the control. Or you can even use sort indirection for an extra level of indirection!!

Comment: Ok done, will switch to some other vcl component.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in sort facility for TStringGrid, so you need to roll your own.  Personally, I use some general purpose sorting code that can sort anything provided a compare function and an exchange function:

```
type
  TCompareIndicesFunction = function(Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer of object;
  TExchangeIndicesProcedure = procedure(Index1, Index2: Integer) of object;

procedure Sort(const First, Last: Integer; Compare: TCompareIndicesFunction; Exchange: TExchangeIndicesProcedure);
begin
  //insert search algorithm here
end;
```

You could look at how Generics.Collections.TArray.Quicksort is implemented to see how to fill in the missing code above.

The essential point is that your `Compare` and `Exchange` functions, which are methods of objects, contain the knowledge of how to compare items in the string grid, and then how to swap them.